# How do I alias a name in nginx w/o aliasing the domain name?

Tags: nginx

I have this line in my config file

```
server_name site.com m.site.com
```

My code checks if the url is `m.site.com` and serves the mobile version. However when I do this going to `m.site.com/abc` will show my code `site.com/abc` which is wrong. If I copy/paste the entire block and change site.com to m.site.com it works fine. But I'd rather not have duplicate config (or code).

Is there a way around this?

Comment: How is your code getting the URL?

Comment: @polynomial: via HttpRequest.Uri but rawurl shows the changed host as well

Answer (score 2):

It is an [ineffective way](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/converting_rewrite_rules.html) even if you check `$http_host` in config. So, the best way is put all common bits in a file and [include](http://wiki.nginx.org/CoreModule#include) it in separate `server` block:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  site.com;
    root         /var/www/localhost/htdocs/site.com;
    include      asp.conf
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  m.site.com;
    root         /var/www/localhost/htdocs/m.site.com;
    include      asp.conf
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices here:

1) Have "duplicate" config blocks for nginx

2) Have your site detect the server name (in PHP, $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] or $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) and serve up a different site depending on what it is.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure the 2nd would work but i am using asp.net anyways. With asp.net i grabbed the url from both HttpRequest.Uri and .rawurl. They both have the changed domain.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using nginx as a reverse proxy, try adding the `proxy_set_header` directive near your `proxy_pass` directive, like this:

```
proxy_pass   http://my.asp.net.hostname:8000;
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
```

This ensures that nginx is passing the Host header verbatim, instead of taking the main server_name.